# Cannot include a header in MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, include, mingw

I'm using SublimeText with MinGW on Windows 7 an wanted to include

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
```

but I get

```
fatal error: boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
```

Couldn't figure out what to do from what I've found here and in Google.

This is the path to the include folder:
C:\MinGW\include\

Should I add something like? (from what I could "understand")

> -I C:/MinGW/include/boost

But it doesn't work...

Comment: It appears that *cstdint.hpp* was [removed from boost.integer](https://github.com/boostorg/integer/commit/05330d178e3683d563b8242a21435a216fb2794a) and can now be found in [boost.config](https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/develop/include/boost/cstdint.hpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **UPDATE:**
>
> "-IC:/MinGW/include"

Oh okay, I figured it out.

So... I have all the necessary libraries here C:\MinGW\include\

But in order to be able to include boost files (C:\MinGW\include\boost) I needed to copy this folder here C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.9.1 which is where MinGW was looking for my files...

So in the end I get C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.9.1\boost with all the necessary libraries inside. Now it works.

Comment: This is really not a good solution - additional headers/libraries should be installed in separate (default) locations and you should specify the required paths at build time so that the compiler can find the relevant files.

Comment: Uhm. Well, unfortunately no one explained how to do it, and I haven't been able to find here or on the Internet. I've found similar questions left unanswered, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've tried a few methods of specifying absolute locations, but didn't work for me. That's why I asked this on here. No one seems to know\help.

Comment: You just need to add the correct `-I` path - experiment until you get it right. See also the gcc manual.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install boost (from boost.org). http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_57_0.html

your `#include` already starts with  `boost/` so it will look in include/boost.